# How to deliver webp format of images to WP REST API

Tags: rest-api, optimization

I use [WP Offload Media Lite plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) to offload upload image to S3. I use raw S3 URL (not CDN) and choose remove file in server option. Then I use [EWWW Image Optimizer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/) to convert image on S3 to .webp format. I run bulk optimize and there are .webp copies on S3. Then I choose JS Webp Rewriting to delivery .webp to my site (because I use Nginx) and it works well. But my partner request me deliver .webp to WP Rest api too. Because when he call : `http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&slug=this-is-post-slug` (GET) , it returns response that has only .jpeg, not .webp. I'm not familiar with WP rest api. How could I do that?

Comment: What would you want the output to be from the REST API - always webps instead of JPGs? At the moment you're using a client side script to do that for your website, so maybe the answer is you expect your REST API consumers to do the same?

Comment: @Rup Yes, I expect my REST API response .webp such as JS webp rewriting do for my website. Is there any options on  EWWW Image Optimizer plugin to setting webp deliver method to REST API or I need to custom manually somewhere in my source code?

Comment: I don't know anything about EWWW Image Optimizer - you'd have to ask them. If there isn't then yes you'll have to reimplement the JavaScript webp rewriting in PHP as a content filter - I'm not sure what that would be, maybe a the_content filter that you set up in a rest_api_init handler.